# MOSFET Cascode Resistance

Tags: mosfet

[image]

Hi, I'm trying to find the resistance Rx in the picture.

Now, usually I would assume that (if channel length modulation is non-zero), that this would be 1/gm2 in parallel with ro2. However, I remember that was when our drain of M2 was connected straight to Vdd (AC ground in small-signal). But in this case, the drain is no longer just AC ground, Rd is there.

**I'm assuming the Rx in this case won't just be 1/gm2 in parallel with ro2 will it?**

Comment: This would be a good time to draw some equivalent circuits and find the resistances by seeing what's in parallel and in series.

Comment: *I'm assuming the Rx in this case won't just be 1/gm2 in parallel with ro2 will it?* Imagine that Rd has a very high value, like 1 Mohm (let's ignore that would influence the DC biasingof the circuit). Then it is easy to see that Rd **does** have an influence on the value of Rx. My point: don't **assume** but use **reasoning**.